# is there a way to implement @JsonView in spring REST service for version 3.2.1?

Tags: spring

@JsonView support for spring Rest service is added from version 4.1. If we want to achieve similar thing in sprng 3.2.1, then how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do it manually. Example given below.

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public String getMessage(@PathVariable Long id)
            throws JsonProcessingException {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.writerWithView(View.Summary.class)
                .writeValueAsString(messageService.get(1L));
    }
  }
```